# Non-nullable instance field 'id' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, class, null, required

could anyone help me with how to manage this problem? I am new to Flutter, I am trying to code exactly likes the course's video, but I got this problem:
2. How could I change the 'status' item optional?

```
class Task {
 int id;
 String title;
 DateTime date;
 String priority;
 int status; // 0 - Incomplete, 1 - Complete

 Task({this.title, this.date, this.priority, this.status});
 Task.withId({this.id, this.title, this.date, this.priority, this.status});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a null safety problem

solutions

make int nullable

```
int? id; // preferred
```

or

when calling constructor use required keyword

```
 Task({required this.id})
```

or

initialize default value to id

```
int id = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have named parameters constructors

```
Task({...});
```

and you do not specify `required` keyword in front of a variable the variable is optional. But, because your code is written in null-safety way, you must give it value or the other way it would be assigned null (which is illegal in this case).

**Nullable var**
If you want your value to be null-assignable you can write:

```
int? status;
```

Then you have to remember to check if the variable is null or not before you use it.

**Default value**
Another way is to use default value in the constructor:

```
Task({..., this.status = 0});
```

**Required value**
Or you can force developer to give it a value:

```
Task({..., required this.status});
```

**Dartz**
Another way is to use Option variable from Dartz package:

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
...
Option<int> status;
Task({..., required this.status});
```

then you can pass none() or some(1) as a status.

```
Task(..., status: none());
Task(..., status: some(0));
```